# Data type long can not be converted

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I have a problem with error which show me problem with long data type in this part of code:

```
If Not filename Then
            Call Form15.Show()
            TextBox1.Clear()
```

here is full code:

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        Dim filename As String
        Dim regCis = TextBox1.Text
        filename = TextBox1.Text
        Dim zakazCis As Double
        Dim found As Boolean = False
        found = True

        If (Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, zakazCis)) Then
            zakazCis = TextBox2.Text
        Else
            zakazCis = Nothing
        End If

        Dim basePath As String = "C:\_Montix a.s. - cloud\iMontix\Testy"
        Dim filePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(basePath, filename & ".lbe")

        'Napojeni tabulky
        Dim table As DataTable = SdfDataSet.Tables("List1")
        Me.Refresh()

        'Vytvoreni dotazu
        Dim expression As String
        expression = ("[Čísla dílů] = '" & regCis & "'")
        Dim foundRows() As DataRow

        Me.PictureBox1.Invalidate()
        Dim bla = "Label10"



        'vykonani dotazu

        foundRows = table.Select(expression)



        If Not filename Then
            Call Form15.Show()
            TextBox1.Clear()
        Else

            If (foundRows(0)(2) = zakazCis) Then
                'souhlasí regCis a zakcis

                PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\_Montix a.s. - cloud\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsApplication17\WindowsApplication17\img\tick.png")
                Label10.BackColor = Color.Green
                Me.Controls(bla).Text = "SPRÁVNĚ"
                fileprint.PrintThisfile(filePath)
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000)
                SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
                TextBox2.Clear()
                TextBox2.Select()
                Button6.Hide()
                PictureBox1.Hide()
                Label10.Hide()



            Else
                'NEsouhlasí regCis a zakcis

                PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\_Montix a.s. - cloud\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsApplication17\WindowsApplication17\img\cross.png")
                Label10.BackColor = Color.Red
                Form15.Show()
                TextBox2.Clear()
                TextBox2.Select()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

and here is code from form15

```
Public Class Form15
    Private Sub Button11_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Do you known where is a problem?

Comment: You should read [ask] and take the [tour].  That is not the complete error message and the line you indicate seems unlikely to cause it; the `Else` portion seems more likely.  Also what exactly are you wanting to test with `If Not FileName` where filename is a string?  `Option Strict` seems not to be in place either

Comment: I want to test exist value from textbox1. How can I fix it and declare it ? When I repleace it by msgbox everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a string in a boolean expression. I guess, you might have added the string instead of the boolean by mistake. ('found' instead of 'filename')

```
If Not found Then
        Call Form15.Show()
        TextBox1.Clear()
Else
```

Comment: filename is a text in textbox1 and base on this text I search in database. Now  I would like to interpret what is happen when text from textbox1 will not in database. can you help me?